# Is there any way to print multArray in sub-program print() from createArray()?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I would like to have two sub-programs `createArray()` and `print()`. `Print()` will require the `multArray` variable from `createArray()` and I have written the program so that the array is not created locally in main. I realise that I could have set `createArray` up as `createArray(int a, int b)` however I decided against it. Will this come back to bite me now or is there still a way for me to accomplish this without making the suggested change?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
        String choiceInput;
        boolean stop = false;
        boolean firstTime = true;


        while (stop == false){

            if (firstTime == true) {
                System.out.println("Welcome To The Multiplications Table Creator!" + newLine + newLine + "Would you like to:" + newLine + newLine + "Create          Print          Exit" + newLine + newLine + "Please enter one of the above in the space below: ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Welcome Back!" + newLine + newLine + "Would you like to:" + newLine + newLine + "Create          Print          Exit" + newLine + newLine + "Please enter one of the above in the space below: ");
            }
            choiceInput = scan.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            if (choiceInput.equals("CREATE")) {
                createArray();
                firstTime = false;

                for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
                    System.out.println(newLine);
                }

            }
            else if (choiceInput.equals("PRINT")) {
                print();
                firstTime = false;
            }
            else if (choiceInput.equals("EXIT")) {
                for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
                    System.out.println(newLine);
                }
                System.out.print("Thank you for using the program!");
                for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
                    System.out.println(newLine);
                }
                stop = true;
            }
            else System.out.println("You did not enter one of the above!");
        }
    }

    public static int[][] createArray() {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newLine = System.lineSeparator();
        int a;
        int b;

        System.out.print("How big would you like your multiplication table to be? (A x B)" + newLine + "A: ");
        a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a + " x ");
        b = s.nextInt();

        int[][] multArray = new int[a][b];

        for (int countA = 1; countA <= a; countA++) { 
            for (int countB = 1; countB <= b; countB++) {
                multArray[countA - 1][countB - 1] = countA * countB;
            }

        }
        System.out.print("Creating .");
        delay(1000);
        System.out.print(" .");
        delay(1000);
        System.out.print(" .");
        delay(1000);
        System.out.println(newLine + "Done.");
        return multArray;

    }

    public static void print() {
        **//This is where I need to print multArray created above is it possible?**
    }

    public static void delay(int millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException exp) {  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sidenote 1: define a global scanner and reuse it, no need to define multiple of each. sidenote 2: `if(!stop)` and `if(firstTime)` reads itself better than comparing to a bool value in my eyes.

Comment: You did not store the outcome of the function `createArray()`, therefore you can't use `print()` properly since.
You will need to store it as a private member and then access it in `print()` or pass it as a parameter to `print()`.

Comment: Is the `return multArray;` not sufficient in this case? In terms of code what would this require me to do?

Comment: To be able to use it after you have to assign it a name when you return it `int [][] array = createArray();`, and then pass it to the print method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createArray` method returns an `int[][]` array, so you can do something like this

`int[][] multiArray = createArray();`*// storing the outcome of create array method in multiArray*

Now change your `print` method to accept an `int[][]` array, something like this

`public static void print(int[][] multiArray);` *// print method which accepts an int[][] array as parameter*

pass `multiArray` to print method when you call print method something like this

`print(multiArray)` *// passing the earlier outcome of createArray which is multiArray to print method.*

Now inside print method you can print `multiArray`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, however where in the code will the `int[][] multiArray = createArray();` go?

Comment: The place where you are calling createArray method currently. Its inside this if condition `if (choiceInput.equals("CREATE"))`, just replace this line `createArray();` to `int[][] multiArray = createArray();`.

Comment: I am actually receiving an error now when calling `print(multiArray)` saying that the variable can not be resolved why is this happening?

Comment: @MarkSharpe You have to declare `multiArray` before the if condition. `int[][] multiArray;` and then inside if condition do this `multiArray = createArray();`

Comment: @MarkSharpe It happens because the scope of that variable is within that if block and other blocks can't see that variable, to avoid this problem either declare it before if condition that is inside while loop or you can also make it class variable that means you can declare it before while loop. Hope this clears your doubt. Let me know if you are still facing problems.

Comment: It was already declared with `int[][] multiArray = createArray();` however for some reason the `print(multiArray);` in the `else if` was disconnected from this. Even when I declare above and assign in the `if` the `print(multiArray)` gives the error of not being initialised with a fix of setting it = to null.

Comment: @MarkSharpe Yeah forgot you have initialize the array to null, here is working code http://ideone.com/NfyM5j. Note - use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals` to check strings. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate through your y- and x-axis. This example should print all row elements for each column. Therefore the first for-loop iterates through your rows and the second through every element in the individual row.

```
public static void printArray(int[][] multArray) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < multArray.lenght(); i++)
       {
          for(int j = 0; j < multArray[i].lenght(); j++)
          {
             System.out.printf("%5d ", multArray[i][j]);
          }
          System.out.println();
       }
```